# Removing duplicate rows in select query

Tags: oracle, select, duplicates

I have data like below. I want to select only one `task_id` with higher priority.

```
TASK_ID : 13912 = 2 rows
          13913 = 3 rows

Task_ID owner   priority
13912   JUNGIL  99
13912   BANCS   1
13913   JUNGIL  99
13913   BANCS   1
13913   AIL     2
```

There much more data but I have to select only one.

Comment: To remove duplicates use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate rows in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816851/duplicate-rows-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Some badly needed practice with [`keep ... dense_rank first`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm) ([thanks for the reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25064335/266304) Gordon Linoff):

```
select task_id,
  max(owner) keep (dense_rank last order by priority) as owner,
  max(priority) keep (dense_rank last order by priority) as priority
from t42
group by task_id
order by task_id;

   TASK_ID OWNER        PRIORITY
---------- ---------- ----------
     13912 JUNGIL             99 
     13913 JUNGIL             99
```

Or if the highest priority is 1 then:

```
select task_id,
  max(owner) keep (dense_rank first order by priority) as owner,
  max(priority) keep (dense_rank first order by priority) as priority
from t42
group by task_id
order by task_id;

   TASK_ID OWNER        PRIORITY
---------- ---------- ----------
     13912 BANCS               1 
     13913 BANCS               1
```

You could also do it with a subquery and analytics:

```
select task_id, owner, priority
from (
  select task_id, owner, priority,
    dense_rank() over (partition by task_id order by priority) as rnk
  from t42
)
where rnk = 1
order by task_id;

   TASK_ID OWNER        PRIORITY
---------- ---------- ----------
     13912 BANCS               1 
     13913 BANCS               1
```

... but the `keep` approach is simpler. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3214b/1) showing both.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need just a `group by` query like this:

```
select max(priority), task_id
  from <YOUR_TABLE_HERE>
 group by t.task_id
```

if you want to have all the row's columns

```
select t.*
  from t
  join (
    select max(priority) priority, task_id
      from t
     group by t.task_id
  )t2 on t.task_id = t2.task_id and t.priority = t2.priority
```